# Check if cookie exists #2

Tags: vb.net, cookies, geckofx

Trying to start with VB.Net and having problem

We have such a [Class](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-8.0/src/cc1a16ddce40/Skybound.Gecko/CookieManager.cs) in C#.
How to check if cookie exist? Exactly, how to set input object "Cookie" for a function CookieExist? How to create it using GeckoFx?
For example, how to find cookie with the name "Test2"?

Please, make an example.

I'm going crazy with VB.Net

P.S. I rarely write to forums if can find info on my own but VB.Net have too few examples in the net. ;/

Comment: Can you give more detail about the kind of application you're creating?

Comment: I'm trying to use GeckoFx and work with Gecko.CookieManager.
Adding, Removing works successfully because there are no such input arguments as Cookie object.

In class I gave there is a "public sealed class Cookie" but when I try to use it, it shows an error about "This class is friendly" (smth like this).

Comment: For example, to print all cookies from host, I use smth like this: http://pastebin.com/v1aqhD2X

Maybe, I'm wrong, but it's one of first projects. However, this works.

Answer (score 3):

I think the code below will help you:

```
Dim cookieValue As String = "Value of cookie"
Dim cookieName As String = "CookieName"

Dim realCookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName)
If IsNothing(realCookie) Then
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue))
End If
```

Comment: As I understand, This is not working with Gecko, which I posted in first post, is it? I need how to solve my issue with the Gecko.Cookie class ;/